# $atts are user input, how to sanitize and escape in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins, shortcode, sanitize

I create a shortcode in WordPress. Shortcode code below:

```
function wp_test_shortcode($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    =>  'TESTTEST',
        'thumb' =>  ''
    ),$atts);

    $thumb = $atts['thumb'] ? $atts['thumb'] : 'https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/'.$atts['id'].'/0.jpg';

    return '<div data-id="'.$atts['id'].'" data-thumb="'.$thumb.'" ></div>';
}
add_shortcode('test','wp_test_shortcode');
```

Now my question is, Since $atts are user input, how to sanitize and escape.

Comment: How are `$atts` user input?

Comment: This is what you need https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Finally, I get a solution.

Comment: $atts are considered an input to anyone who has Contributor role or above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming someone with a Wordpress Contributor role is the bad actor here, Monzur Alam is right - you have to sanitize the attributes.

```php
function wp_test_shortcode($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    =>  'TESTTEST',
        'thumb' =>  ''
    ),$atts);
    
    // Sanitize Inputs
    
    $id = sanitize_text_field($atts['id']);
    $thumb = sanitize_text_field($atts['thumb']);
    
    $thumb = $thumb ? $thumb : 'https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/'.$atts['id'].'/0.jpg';

    // Escape Outputs
    
    return '<div data-id="'.esc_attr($id)).'" data-thumb="'.esc_url($thumb).'" ></div>';
} 

add_shortcode('test','wp_test_shortcode');
```